# What is the VB.net code for this C# code:

Tags: c#-to-vb.net

if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { btnEnd.Enabled = true; }));
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If InvokeRequired Then
    BeginInvoke(DirectCast(Function() 
    btnEnd.Enabled = True

End Function, Action))
End If
```